# How To Stretch Background Across Empty Space

Tags: html, css

## How To Stretch Background Across Empty Space for Inline Elements

---

Hello, StackOverflow community! I had a question in regards to a problem I have been having when CSS styling my pages, as to the techniques that can be employed in order to get an inline element's background (using `background: grey` for example) across any empty space surrounding it, without exceeding the boundaries specified by it's content. As an example, let me put a snippet:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 10em;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 6.5em;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example Snippet</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above example, I wrote some code to demo the problem I am having. I don't know how to get the background to size up to the scale of it's container. Does anybody know any technniques to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about the height of the `li`s? If so, you can just give the `ul` a `display: flex;`.

Comment: @SeanStopnik Yes I am referring to the height of the `li`'s. However, it kind of loses the alignment and I was hoping to keep the custom written CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your `li` to take up as much space within it's parent container? If so I included a JSFiddle from your code. In it, I removed the positioning from your `li` and `ul`. and added `display:inline-block` to your li's so they could get padding added to them as inline elements ignore padding all together.

Here is the fiddle let me know if that is what you were looking for.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msk0yL7g/3/)

Comment: THANK YOU! This is the answer I was looking for. I have upvoted this answer, and marked it as correct!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the height of the `li`, you can just give the `ul` a `display: flex;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmeoypgj/4/

Comment: +1 for the idea but I'm not too fond of using CSS frameworks, and it gets rid of the other styling as well

Comment: There is no css framework here. I just removed the other styling, as some of it was not needed.

Comment: what I meant by the use of the framework was the use of Flexbox to fix the problem, and as mentioned before, the removal of the original styling.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but you could create a li-class or id and use the old border box model:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 10em;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  
  
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bgInside {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 6.5em;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example Snippet</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="bgInside">Element 1</li>
        <li class="bgInside">Element 2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: upvoted for the idea, but that wasn't the effect I was looking to achieve. Thank you for answering, however!